# Is is possible to use to use git-flow (or vanilla git), to have different set of (build) files on master & develop branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, bower, git-flow

Is is possible to use git-flow (or a vanilla git chain of commands, or another gitXXX candy), to have a different set of files on **master** (i.e release) & **develop** branches ?

Since git repos are used for deployment (see below), I want my **develop** branch to contain *strictly source files*, but when I merge it into **master**, I want master(release) branch to also contain release/compiled outputs, zip files, optimized resources etc.

NOTE: The question seeks for:

- an **example scenario** and the **git/git-flow commands** that would keep `develop` and other branches clean of compiled/build stuff, while only `master` has them in an extra `./build` directory.
- The two branches should still remain in good sync and the whole branching/merging process should be automatic, painless and safe. Perhaps some day it becomes a standard git-flow feature & practice.
- I know this is not recommended, cumbersome, non optimal etc, but bear in mind that :

  - git repos are increasingly used for deployment - eg see http://bower.io that uses strictly **git repos** and **semver** tags to deploy compiled stuff.
  - the question asks **if its possible**, not if **its desirable** or a **good practice**. If it is **not possible**, a good explanation is desirable.

Comment: You really don't want compiled binaries in your git repo. That is horrific bloat. Have your build system copy the results into a named/dated folder automatically or something.

Comment: I agree, having build files on git is a bad idea - But I see it happening quite often and I wanted to at least have my 'develop' branch clean and tidy... (if u can't avoid it, try to enjoy it)

Comment: I'm just particularly bitter because I maintained a pristine git repo at work. It was source only, so it cloned really fast. Then someone dumped in a buncha DLLs. That alone added a few hundred MB. T_T

Comment: As mentioned in the revised description, http://bower.io uses strictly git repos and semver tags to deploy compiled stuff. This answer does not provide an answer to the question, it just refutes it.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want to use Git as a build or deployment system. That's not what Git does, and it's not considered good practice to include compiled artefacts in your repository.

Consider using a proper build system for your environment.

**Edit for the updated question:**

If you *really want to do this*, it is perfectly possible to include build artefacts in one branch and not in another. You can simply `add` them in your `build` branch:

```
git checkout -b build
# Run build command
git add build/
git commit -m "Add build artefacts"
```

When you switch back to `master` your build directory will not be present.

As [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414355/magnus-back) [mentions below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863837/354577), this can lead to some unpleasantness during merges, though if you only ever merge from `master` into `build` and never the other way around you should be fine in that regard. It does also add some mental baggage that you need to keep in mind while working.

If you are going down this path I would recommend only keeping build commits that result in a tagged release. Then you can include the tag in the commit message. I would probably also squash the source commits into one commit for the build phase.

To run a new build, your approach would be something like

```
git checkout build
git merge -s recursive -X theirs --squash master
# Run build command
```

Now, depending on whether the build is one you want to keep around or not, you can either keep it

```
git commit -a -m "Update build files for version 1.2.3"
git checkout master
git tag -a 1.2.3
```

or discard it

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

I still don't like the idea of committing build artefacts in your source repository, and the folks at Bower.io are [aware that this is a problem and are working on a solution](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/455#issuecomment-18184381) (emphasis mine):

> > Is it recommended that all bower packages should have build files in their Git repos?
>
> Nope. An npm-like publishing model is being worked on to support the publication of built assets to the Bower server, thereby avoiding the post-install and **check-in-of-build-products antipatterns**. Until then, there's no nice way to install a package like jQuery Mobile.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to have been much progress on this over the last ten months.

Comment: I'm with the Chris guy here.  GIT provides no automated way to do anything like that.  In our environments, build artifacts and their archive policies are a function of the build system, not the version control system.

Comment: I agree with the rationale against doing it (see comment on the question it self) - but still this answer doesn't really tackle what is asked.

Comment: As mentioned in the revised question, http://bower.io uses strictly git repos and semver tags to deploy compiled stuff. This answer does not provide an answer to the question, it just refutes it.

Comment: @AgelosPikoulas, I have updated my answer for your revised question. Hopefully you find it more helpful. (Though I do believe that an answer of "don't do that" is sometimes appropriate.)

Comment: @Chris thanks, the revised one is more appropriate Q&A :-) I voted it up but I'll leave as non-answered in case a more complete / git-flow answer comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with the other comments – do *not* commit binary artifacts along with the source code. Depending on the size of your binaries you may severely impact the size of your repository (and hence the time necessary to e.g. clone it) and even make it prohibitively large.

But, to answer your question, it's totally fine to have different sets of files on two branches. Merges between such branches *can* be problematic if you're merging from a branch with a superset of files since Git is going to want to include those files in the merge, but in your case it's the destination branch that contains the superset of files and then you're good.

Comment: I think this is the answer that is closer to what is asked for - can you please provide a simplistic example & the chain of commands with possible problems and their workarounds

Comment: @AgelosPikoulas: Example of what, exactly? That files added to branch A will be included in branch B if you merge from A to B?

Comment: It would be great if we could have a git-flow aware (or vanilla git) scenario and the commands that would keep develop *clean* of compiled/build stuff, while master has them in an extra `./build` directory, but are still  in good sync. Is that even possible ?